# видимость значения при синхронизированном изменении

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Насколько известно, изменив `volatile` переменную, мы остаёмся уверенны, что остальные потоки, которые будут её читать, получат новое значение. Причина тому ясна: значения переменных не кэшируются (конечно, там больше происходящего, но сейчас важна суть). Так вот мне стало неясно, а что происходит с видимостью изменений `non-volatile` переменных при синхронизации?

В достоверном источнике сказано следующее:

> Синхронизация вынуждает запись данных происходить в основную память, и если поле полностью защищено синхронизированными методами или блоками, объявлять его `volatile` для параллельного доступа не обязательно.

Так вот, **вопрос:** а как это случается, почему же ключевое слово `volatile` нам теперь не нужно? Нам нужны `synchronized` getter'ы и setter'ы, али же достаточно синхронизировано прочитать? А может только записать?

Поясню часть вопроса про getter'ы и setter'ы:
Пусть есть код:

```
class A {
    int n=1;
    public void change(){
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
            synchronized (this){
                n=3*n+4;
            }
    } 
}
```

в `main(String[] args)` того же пакета, что и класс `A`:

```
A a = new A();
new Thread(a::change).start();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
System.out.println(a.n);
```

И здесь возникает вопрос.
Давайте сейчас забудем про то, что переменная `n` могла переполниться, а потом через наш sleep в 10 секунд снова стать равной 1. И забудем про то, что когда мы читаем `n` она может быть в некотором "неустойчивом" состоянии.
Так вот, достаточно ли было синхронизации в методе `change()`? Гарантирует ли она проталкивание в `main memory` нашей переменной `n`? Т.е. по факту вопрос такой: правда ли, что не будет такого, что через 10 секунд сна доставая `a.n` мы получим там 1, ибо значение этого поля пока лежит в кэше?

А если изменить последнюю строчку в `main(String[] args)` на:

```
synchronized (a){
    System.out.println(a.n);
}
```

Теперь точно всё хорошо и проблем с видимостью изменений не будет? Как так устроен этот аспект механизма синхронизации? Т.е. `change()` не проталкивал в `main memory`, а при синхронизированном чтении сразу проталкивалось всё?... Или синхронизации в `change()` было достаточно?

---

В приложение к ответу буду очень благодарен увидеть цитаты из документации (с переводом на русский язык) к Java с ссылкой на них.

---

[Здеся](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364054/when-are-changes-in-synchronized-block-visible-to-other-threads/6364077#6364077) и [тута](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) есть важные мысли, но я хочу получить ответ на всё-таки другой вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Модификаторы `volatile` и `synchronized` решают ведь не только проблему с кэшированием. Есть ещё масса нюансов, которые требуется учитывать в многопоточном программировании. Например, *reordering*. Есть ряд случаев, в которых доступ к переменным (полям объектов,  статическим полям и элементам массива) может выполниться в порядке, отличном от указанного в программе. Компилятор свободен в расположении инструкций с целью оптимизации. Процессоры могут выполнять инструкции в ином порядке в ряде случаев. Данные могут перемещаться между регистрами, кэшами процессора и оперативной памятью в порядке, отличном от указанного в программе. Но [JMM](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133) гарантирует сохранение отношений *happens-before* внутри синхронизированных блоков, устанавливая [барьер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) при захвате и освобождении блокировки. Сама семантика слова "синхронизация" говорит за себя. Поток осуществляющий синхронизированный доступ к переменной, синхронизирует своё состояние. Но действительно актуальное состояние переменной для всех возможно только в том случае, если синхронизируются все.

Кроме того, не стоит забывать, что синхронизация используется не только для решения проблемы видимости, но и атомарности. Если один поток захватывает блокировку при доступе к полю, а другой даже не пытается её захватить и, соответственно, проверить её состояние, то толку от блокировки нет, и программа испортит состояние.

**P.S.** Вместо ссылок на документацию приведу ссылки на доклады человека, чьё имя стало нарицательным в этой области.

[Aleksey Shipilёv - Java Memory Model Pragmatics, part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noDnSV7NCtw)
[Aleksey Shipilёv - Java Memory Model Pragmatics, part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ky1_5mabd18)
[Алексей Шипилёв — Близкие Контакты JMM-степени](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6b_dFtujKo)

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей. Но осталось не понятно: если поток Т1 в синхронизированном блоке запишет значение некоторой переменной, а поток T2 без синхронизации прочитает её значение тогда, когда уже ТОЧНО выполнилась строчка записи в T1, то T2 увидит новое значение? Протолкнула ли синхронизация в T1 переменную в память? И обратно: если Т1 без синхронизации записал, а строго после того Т2 синхронизировано прочитал, то увидит ли Т2 новое значение?

Comment: Без синхронизации никаких ТОЧНО не будет. Поток Т2 может никогда не увидеть банального присвоения в Т1.

Comment: Сергей, а подскажите тогда, пожалуйста, если допустим задача P (в Т1) представляет собой просчёт физики игрока (допустим переписывает его координаты в полёте согласно f=mg^2), а задача M (в Т2) представляет собой главный цикл программы и на каждой итерации цикла спрашивает координаты игрока. Вопрос: M обязательно должен захватить блокировку для простого считывания координат игрока? А если блокировка сейчас у P, и вычисления физики долгие? Нельзя просто без синхронизации достать то из P, что там есть? Я вот этого не понимаю. Т.е. Может ли P протолкнуть в память без volatile и T1+T2 synchronize?

Comment: А вы думали почему 3d-движки такие дорогие, сложные и пишутся в основном на C++? :) Без синхронизации нельзя, никак. И это относится не только к Java, кстати. Многопоточность в принципе очень сложная тема. Поэтому многие современные языки и фреймворки предлагают программистам высокоуровневные абстракции, типа акторов и реактивных потоков, чтобы снизить сложность. Если вас интересует эта тема, рекомендую прочитать книгу Брайана Гетца "Java Concurrency in Practice" где кратенько, на 400 страницах, рассказывается, какая это боль.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: `если блокировка сейчас у P, и вычисления физики долгие` - не нужно захватывать блокировку на все вычисление, она нужно только при записи результатова в разделяемые переменные. Более того тут достаточно только volatile (и при записи и при чтении), с ним синхронизация быстрее, так так нужно синхронизировать только в одну сторону (при записи от записывающего в память, а при считывании из памяти к читающему), т.е делать половину работы. Плюс volatile не блокирует ни читателя ни писателя в отличии от synchronized. Так что М может себе читать когда угодно без проблем.